# Devo colocar "event listeners" dentro da função "document ready"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando um event listener para pegar o clique em um elemento com jQuery:

```
$('#elemento').on('click', function () {
    ...
});
```

Minha dúvida é se devo colocar este "event listener" dentro da função "document ready" da forma abaixo ou não precisa?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elemento').on('click', function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Posso deixar ele de fora como no primeiro bloco? Qual é melhor forma de se fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz da primeira forma, colocando dentro do `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`, você estará instruindo o navegador a somente executar seu script após o DOM ser totalmente processado.

Como um arquivo HTML é interpretado de cima para baixo, fazendo da segunda forma e colocando o "listener" fora do `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` você não garante que seu script vá encontrar o elemento com ID `#elemento`. No caso de por exemplo, você ter colocado seu script no `<head>` do seu HTML, ele será executado imediatamente e não será capaz de incializar corretamente seu "event listener".

Uma alternativa é colocar a inicialização do "listener" fora do `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`, mas excutar seu script no final do HTML, antes de fechar a tag `<body>`.

Comment: Além disso o jquery silencia os erros que seriam logados se você estivesse fazendo a mesma coisa (vincular evento a elemento inexistente) em js puro.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Thiago!

Quando você faz

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elemento').on('click', function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Você garante que o evento só esteja disponível quando o documento estiver completamente carregado. Mas isso é um decisão sua, se preferir, pode fazer apenas

```
$('#elemento').on('click', function () {
     alert("Hello!");
});
```

Como diz na documentação

```
[O código] será executado uma vez que a página, Document Object Model (DOM), esteja pronta para o código JavaScript executar [seguramente].
```

[jQuery Doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)